# How to handle a vendor who asks for the solution of an issue they could not solve

Tags: php, programming-practices, web-applications, business-rules

Being a small department of developers, it's not uncommon for us to outsource projects.  We have a set of companies that we really like to work with, very reliable and good local people who appreciate the work.

This has happened a couple times, most recently today: **We receive a project, set it up in our environment, and notice an issue.  Due to them not being able to provide a solution in time, we're forced to find a solve internally.  Then the vendor, who we pay very well, will sometimes ask how we solved the problem.**

Again, this is a rarity, and we have a great relationship with these guys, but I do have some inkling that I should not be handing out the answers to a resource which we're paying.

How should I handle this?  Do I set aside my ego and just say "Thanks for doing a great job, here's your $30k and we finished the project for you by doing this one thing your company was unable to do but now can charge us more to do next time"?

Is it appropriate to tell them I can't give them "company" code/etc?  Would this tarnish our relationship?

Comment: No offense, but this sounds like programmer ego. If you feel that you shouldn't pay them as much because they didn't solve a particular problem, I would let somebody else handle that conversation if you want the relationship to remain great. Otherwise I'd just lock the ego back in it's cage and be graceful in sharing your solution, just like this wonderful community of internet strangers promotes.

Comment: Absolutely no offense taken, as I said I think ego plays a big part in this.  I'm a huge advocate of open-source and amazing communities like stackexchange, but am not sure where the line is drawn for paid contracts.  Appreciate the input!

Comment: Encountered this a few times. Be good neighbours, supply a patch, get some browny points and maybe a discount on the next version...

Answer (score 5):

**Feedback is crucial to maintaining this relationship**

I'd advocate for a more collaborative approach to help you work better together with these vendors. If you value the closeness of this relationship, and want to keep it, open lines of communication that help them serve you better are best.

Consider the fact that almost nothing works perfectly once it is shipped. Real life production code will encounter real life problems that you may need to work with the original coders to fix. They may be true bugs, or just as likely feedback from real-life users on the operation of the system. (if you're not paying for post-production support and maintenance, perhaps you should continue to engage this team)

There's a good chance you'll want them in the loop after delivery. Even if you don't, you want to give frank feedback for work given to help with future projects. Nothing is more frustrating to a software vendor than the lack of honest feedback (I know I am one!). Its like operating in the dark for them. It will also help you test the relationship: if they are receptive to feedback, you've made the relationship stronger and your vendors better. If not, then you know these are not people you want to work with.

Frankly I wouldn't think of these folks as *vendors* but rather *partners*. You want to build their ability to serve you (by giving feedback and educating them about your business/tech requirements as much as possible). You can almost think of it as onboarding an employee -- it takes time and honest feedback to educate somebody on how to work in your environment. If they take feedback and adjust, then its a good fit. If not, then don't continue the relationship.

As for proprietary info, IANAL etc, but its likely your vendors have signed NDAs up the wazzoo, and already have seen this particular proprietary information (the code they developed for you). Even if this vendor is not allowed to see the rest of the system, I can't imagine you couldn't phrase feedback in a way that might be useful to them in serving you better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely appropriate to refuse to release company code (as intellectual assets as the business lawyers would call it) to anyone. Just refuse, and blame the legal team. Your IP is what makes your software company, give it all away and don't be surprised when you find a competitor springing up doing remarkably similar work to you...

Payment... goodwill plays a fair part here, you must be reasonable. There again, you must not be taken advantage of. The first time this happens, fair enough, you can forgive it. If it continues to happen - either downgrade their payment (ie don't offer to pay them as much the on next contract), or charge them back for fixing their work (they can complain, but then you can tell them they have to fulfil the terms of the contract in full or get no payment at all, and might be sued as well for breach)(I wouldn't recommend this course as it always ends badly).

Chances are, a frank discussion with the boss of the other company is required. I would reduce the contract amount next time to make up for the cost to you of fixing their work.

If they still cannot do the job, stop giving them work. Find someone else who can.